# I want to convert the text into JSON format using nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have been trying to convert my integer and string values to JSON format using replacetext processor in NIFI. But I'm facing problem in regular expression. Can anyone suggest me a Regular Expression in search value and replacement value.

Orginal Text format :

```
{Sensor_id:2.4,locationIP:2.2,Sensor_value:A}
```

Expected JSON format

```
{Sensor_id:2.4,locationIP:2.2,Sensor_value:"A"}
```

Processor configuration : 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex `([\w_]+):([a-zA-Z]\w*)` with replacement `$1:"$2"` as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/Nx0YF6/1)

But notice that a valid `JSON` should have quotes in the keys. For example:

```
 {"Sensor_id":2.4,"locationIP":2.2,"Sensor_value":"A"}
```

In this case, I would recommend:

1. Add a ReplaceText processor with the regex `([\w_]+):` and replacement `"$1":`
2. Link the output of the first ReplaceText to another ReplaceText processor with the regex `([\w_"]+):([a-zA-Z]\w*)` and replacement `$1:"$2"`

I hope it helps

EDIT:

If you want to transform   `{Sensor_id:2.4,locationIP:2.2,Sensor_value:A}` into   `{"Sensor_id":"2.4","locationIP":"2.2","Sensor_value":"A"}` you can use only one regex in a single processor:

Regex: `([\w_]+):([.\w]*)` 
Replacement: `"$1":"$2"`

Comment: I'm able represent in this format   {Sensor_id:2.4,locationIP:2.2,Sensor_value:"A"},whereas  im not able to repreesent in JSON Format  {"Sensor_id":2.4,"locationIP":2.2,"Sensor_value":"A"}

Comment: Can you please tell me how to represent the  format {"Sensor_id":2.4,"locationIP":2.2,"Sensor_value":"A"} to this one  {"Sensor_id":"2.4","locationIP":"2.2","Sensor_value":"A"}  using replacement and search value in nifi

Comment: I updated the answer. You can use that regex and replacement in the very first text data.

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: No ,it is not working, it only update to this format {Sensor_id:2.4,locationIP:2.2,"Sensor_value":"A"}

Comment: {"Sensor_id":"2.4","locationIP":"2.2","Sensor_value":"A"} i need in this format bro

Comment: I edited the post 15 minutes ago. It's working now as you can see here https://regex101.com/r/FqcQdP/1